# Use case need another use case

Tags: uml, use-case

I'm modeling use case for game.

Players can resume the game and exit to main menu, but they need to pause the game prior to doing those actions.

What do they look like in use case? Can anyone explain it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The most elegant solution is probably to employ **preconditions**.

I would put the precondition "The game is paused" in all use cases that require the game to be paused on order to execute them. Note that "Pause game" is a separate use case, with no connection with others:

[image]

Preconditions/postconditions are nice and simple mechanism that simplyfies the model drastically and decouples the use cases, avoiding the need to always use connectors. Sometimes the connectors are ok, but each one of them makes the use case model more complex and more rigid and puts more work into it.

"Pause game" is in my opinion an independent action used very often, not just to be able to go to main menu.

**Extend-based solution:**

ON the first sight this is an appropriate solution (User can pause his game and then eventually resume it or go to the main menu):

[image]

Unfortunatelly, only on the first sight. :)
What happens if User pauses his game and then resumes it! This action will affect the extended use case (the game is not paused any more) and this should never happen with extend! Expected behavior is that all extending UCs are independent on each other and on the extended UC (like running in separate threads). Here it is not the case - "Resume game" will "unpause" the game, undoing the effect of the extended UC and in turn disabling all other extending UCs ("Exit to main menu" in this case).

In order to fix this, some additional rules must be added and the whole solution will become too fuzzy und unclear. In addition to breaking the expected extended UC behavior.

That's why I find the preconditions great - they leave all the freedom and possibilities open, with much less modelling overhead and a clear and neat model.

When extended, a use

Comment: I think I'll go with this. I was thinking of using extend but it seems like "Resume" and "Exit" are optional choices. In "Pause" context, yes they are. But in the context where player really mean to exit the game, it is no longer an option. What do you think?

Comment: Cool! Have fun and a successfull game! ;)

Answer (score 0):

So your *Resume* and *Exit* use cases necessarily **include** *Pause* use case.
Try to model this sentence and post your result.

Comment: I would not use include in this case, because it makes ver rigid solution and impossible to pause the game out of context of snother action (here "exiting to menu" or "resuming"). Besides, it is pretty weird to see a use case "Resume game" that includes "Pause game". Probably the better solution would be to extend "Exit to menu" and "Resume game" from "Pause game", but that also requires connectors between use cases and makes the model more rigid (extension points, extension rules, etc).

Comment: If I well understood the solution must be rigid I mean you can not exit without pausing before. You can also model the fact that the User can pause out of context of another action. In the Other hand Exit and Resume are not extension of Pause because their are not another kind of pause they need/use it.

Comment: I did not mean "rigid" in that sense, of course it cannot leave without pausing the game. I meant rigid in sense that does not leave the possibility to pause without exiting, pause is simply made part of exiting or resuming (which does not reflect good the reality). Use case Extend on the other hand has nothing to do with class inheritance, please refer to UML for more details. Extend is actually much better in this situation than include (at least does not make it so rigid).

Comment: I get the idea, you put "Pause" independently so it makes impossible for player to "only pause" the game. be that as it may, can I put a direct association between actor and "Pause" use case while including it in "Resume" and "Exit"? So that, player can pause without resuming or exiting the game

Comment: Theoretically, you can also put the direct link, but... Hoewevern if is not very common to see in practice, because included uses cases are typically designed to be reused and not "invoked" as independent units. Besides, you would then need even more associations and relationships and that makes the model too overloaded and harder to maintain.